# PHP tree menu nested lists problem

Tags: php

My code for some reason is displaying my nested lists for my tree menu all wrong can someone help me correct this problem? So that my nested lists are nested correctly for my tree menu.

Here is my PHP code.

```
function category_tree($parent = 0, $parent_url = ''){
    echo "<ol>";
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
    $q = "SELECT id, category, url FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '" . $parent . "' ORDER BY category asc";
    $r = mysqli_query($mysqli, $q);
    while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($r) ){
        $url = $parent_url . $rs['url'];
        echo '<li><a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $rs['category'] . ' Category Link">' . $rs['category'] . '</a></li>';
        category_tree($rs['id'], $url);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($r);
    echo "</ol>";
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the procedural mysqli interfaces?

Comment: why whats the problem with using them?

Comment: You might want to look into other storage strategies for your hierarchical data. [This one](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database), for example, could replace your recursive database calls with a 1-2 total calls.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking further, I'd say you need to call `category_tree` before echoing the closing tag of the `LI` element:

```
    echo '<li><a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $rs['category'] . ' Category Link">' . $rs['category'] . '</a>';
    category_tree($rs['id'], $url);
    echo '</li>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Most probably no of active resultset goes too many.

Free the result set before recursive call. Populate all rows of a resultset to a PHP $array. Then Free that resultset. Then use a loop to print tree elements(as u r doing) and to find further child tree.  It could help you.